# How to check radio button Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

How to check radio button?
I need that if `$type == '1'` check input and set value = `1`

I tried:

**First Input:**

```
<input type="radio" 
       name="sex[]" 
       ng-init="formData.sex = '<?=($type == '1' ? '1' : null)?>" 
       ng-model="formData.sex"' 
       required>
```

**Second input:**

```
   <input type="radio" 
           name="sex[]" 
           ng-init="formData.sex = '<?=($type == '2' ? '2' : null)?>" 
           ng-model="formData.sex"' 
           required>
```

When I submit form I see that `formData.sex = true`, so Angular JS gets value from second input howether is selected first, because condition `$type == '1'` is true.

Comment: Yes, I tried, updated question, problem is that there are two radio buttons on page, Angular JS gets value from second. See question

Answer (score 0):

You still need a value :

```
<input type="radio" 
   name="sex" 
   value="1"
   ng-init="formData.sex = '<?=($type == '1' ? '1' : null)?>" 
   ng-model="formData.sex"' 
   required>

<input type="radio" 
   name="sex" 
   value="2"
   ng-init="formData.sex = '<?=($type == '2' ? '2' : null)?>" 
   ng-model="formData.sex"' 
   required>
```

Comment: For what value if I do submit via Angular JS? Tried, does not help me

Answer (score 0):

Try to see this [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/viyxcgMn63zKR8LkqJP0?p=preview) with Plunker

If type is 1 then the first radio button is checked; if type is 2 then radio button 2 is check

is this what are you looking for?

```
<body ng-app="radioExample">
  <script>
  angular.module('radioExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

      $scope.type = '2';

    }]);
</script>
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">

  <input type="radio" 
       name="sex" 
       value = '1'
       ng-init="{{sex = type == '1' ? '1' : '2'}}"
       ng-model="sex" 
       required> <label>1</label>

  <input type="radio" 
       name="sex" 
       value = '2'
       ng-init="{{sex = type == '2' ? '2' : '1'}}"
       ng-model="sex" 
       required> <label>2</label>

       <br/><br/> Sex is now {{sex}}

  </form>

</body>
```